# I am not able to access a shared folder data from a remote IP address

Tags: windows-7, java, ubuntu-12.04, shared-folders

```
File file = new File("//192.168.1.100/sharename/sharefolder/User2.jpeg");
System.out.println(""+file.exists());
```

I am not able to access file named "User2.jpg" available on given `IP address` from `Java` Program.
Please help what i do wrong.

Given `IP` is having Operating System `Win7` and i am requested from `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`

Comment: That file is exist on remote location but program return result false.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 
Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).